# How to Skip few entries within a table if main entry does not exist?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following table
Input
Here I am trying to skip few entries based on a main entry please find more details in the images attached.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Main table is generated from many tables.

Sorry for not providing the query and proper snapshot of table as i am not supposed to share them online.

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to 'skip a few entries', could you explain this further?

Comment: @RichBenner Hi here there is a Main entry which has to present for a client with few string values which may vary. however the Main entry Value may vary. 
 if that entry does not exist then a set entries need to be discarded.
In the above example there exist entry "25  100857   Scheme Status   client found eligible  2016-11-23 15:18:38.000 "

Comment: @RichBenner 
so set of entries should be considered with status id "100858"
lets take clientid 26 where there is main entry "26 100857  Scheme Status  client not found eligible   2016-11-23 15:19:38.000" where second last value for field "Value" which is "client not found eligible" is not the expected so the later set of entries with StatusID =100858 need to be skipped .

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE 
                (CLIENTID INT,
                STATUSID NVARCHAR(200),
                STATUS NVARCHAR(200),
                VALUE NVARCHAR(200),
                CREATEDDATE DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @T 
VALUES  (25,100857,'SCHEME STATUS','CLIENT FOUND ELIGIBLE','2016-11-23 15:18:38:000'),
        (25,100858,'REASON FOR DECLINING TO APPLY','TOO UNWELL','2016-11-23 15:18:38:000'),
        (25,100858,'REASON FOR DECLINING TO APPLY','NOT INTRESTED','2016-11-23 15:18:38:000'),
        (25,100858,'REASON FOR DECLINING TO APPLY','UNDECIDED','2016-11-23 15:18:38:000'),
        (25,100859,'ELIGIBLE TO APPLY','YES','2016-11-23 15:18:38:000'),
        (26,100857,'SCHEME STATUS','CLIENT NOT FOUND ELIGIBLE','2016-11-23 15:18:38:000'),
        (26,100858,'REASON FOR DECLINING TO APPLY','TOO UNWELL','2016-11-23 15:18:38:000'),
        (26,100858,'REASON FOR DECLINING TO APPLY','NOT INTRESTED','2016-11-23 15:18:38:000'),
        (26,100858,'REASON FOR DECLINING TO APPLY','UNDECIDED','2016-11-23 15:18:38:000'),
        (26,100859,'ELIGIBLE TO APPLY','YES','2016-11-23 15:18:38:000')

SELECT * FROM @T 
WHERE CLIENTID IN (SELECT CLIENTID FROM @T WHERE STATUS = 'SCHEME STATUS' AND  VALUE = 'CLIENT FOUND ELIGIBLE') OR 
      STATUSID NOT IN (SELECT STATUSID+1 FROM @T WHERE STATUS = 'SCHEME STATUS' AND  VALUE = 'CLIENT NOT FOUND ELIGIBLE')
```

Comment: Check this may be it will give idea to implement your codes.

Comment: Yes I did by getting the latest entries and then Pivot them later case statement and finally Cross join.  I dint post the code as the field names all are different.

Comment: Then why you are not tick my answer?

Comment: In the query you have given  STATUSID+1 which wont be the case  and the order of ID wont be same.